# Android - Communication between Activity and Service in another Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, communication

I am writing a Tracking App in Android.

I have got a Service implements LocationListener, which does all the stuff with location and writing to database, and Activity.

I would like to run Service in new thread to optimize my app. I want also to send both sides messsages from Service to Activity, which will show info about location.

I bind service, like it is mentioned in [Bind to Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binding) section and implement using a Messenger. Next I tried to do:

```
 Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            bindService(new Intent(this, GPSLogger.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

App is working, but all the GPSLogger stuff is doing in main thread.

Is it any way to repair this?

Comment: call `bindService` just in UI thread, it is async operation, not blocking anything, btw if your `Service` writes anything to sqlite db, you probably can do it easier by creating a custom `ContentProvider`, so no need for bindinf to your `Service`

Comment: @pskink ok, I understand that when I **bindService** it get back an IBinder that gives me a handle to the Service object and then I use it to pass data.  
I call **startService** function inside new Thread() { run() {...} } function, next I start thread and as I said it seems that all the GPSLogger stuff is doing in main thread. I also check it by calling **Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()**  in GPSLogger and it says that it is in main thread. How to start GPSLogger service in new thread?

Comment: you have to launch a new thread by yourself, see for example how `android.app.IntentService` does it

Comment: but honestly i have no idea why you need a new thread for something that doesn't block the ui thread...

Answer (score 0):

Regular services run in main thread.

You can use `IntentService` instead. It is a job queue with a single bg thread.

If you insist on using the base `Service` class then you'll have to spawn your own threads.

Comment: I tried to use `IntentService` but it seems that all the things are running in main thread. How to check what thread is working? I use `Handler` and `ServiceConnection` for Activity and Service communication. Will it work with `IntentService`?

Comment: When using IntentService you need to do the work in the `onHandleIntent` method, which runs in a background thread.